# Android Studio - Add Caption when selecting a picture from gallery

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a caption when I select an image from the gallery. I currently have it where I can add a caption when i take a picture through the camera, but now need to do the same for selecting an image from the gallery. 
Very new to android so could you please elaborate where i should put the code?

Thank you.

Comment: Add a caption *to what*? Where will this caption come from?

Comment: Apologies, add a caption to an image that is taken from the gallery.